# How to share the jsconfig within one big project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Since we found a lot of the components are shareable between seller website and buyer website, we decided to use single repository to manage our e-commerce website.

[image: Folder Structure]

Here comes the problem, when we define the `jsconfig.json` in root as below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/buyer/*": ["buyer/src/*"],
      "@/seller/*": ["seller/src/*"],
      "@/common/*": ["common/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  }
}
```

Also, we define our `vue.config.js` inside `buyer/` and `seller/` respectively.

```
// seller/vue.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: '/',
  transpileDependencies: true,
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the page
      entry: 'seller/src/main.js',
      title: 'Supersave | Seller',
    },
  },
});
```

So when we run the command `VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=./seller/vue.config.js vue-cli-service serve`, it will encounter the following error message:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/common/components/BaseDialog.vue' in '/User/path/to/my/project/seller/src/pages'
```

Any solutions are welcome and appreciated! Thanks in advance, cheers.